# WP CLI Not Displaying All Tables

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am trying to do some simple queries to figure out how a plugin is saving its information. Basically I was getting a really annoying error, and figured out the custom template content was missing on my local. Every other setting/content was transferred over into the database export from the live site. However, for some reason `wp db tables` is only showing a few of the tables. I checked wp-config, and checked the database through my SQL GUI. Did wp db check and it listed all the tables. However, `wp db tables` simply is giving wrong information, and any `wp db search` is not searching the tables that it for some reason is not display. Am I missing something? (for basic reasons, I replaced the name of my local directory and database name with the placeholder clientsite).

```
clientsite % wp db check
clientsite.wp_commentmeta                          OK
clientsite.wp_comments                             OK
clientsite.wp_duplicator_packages                  OK
clientsite.wp_email                                OK
clientsite.wp_links                                OK
clientsite.wp_my_calendar                          OK
clientsite.wp_my_calendar_categories               OK
clientsite.wp_my_calendar_events                   OK
clientsite.wp_my_calendar_locations                OK
clientsite.wp_options                              OK
clientsite.wp_postmeta                             OK
clientsite.wp_posts                                OK
clientsite.wp_term_relationships                   OK
clientsite.wp_term_taxonomy                        OK
clientsite.wp_termmeta                             OK
clientsite.wp_terms                                OK
clientsite.wp_usermeta                             OK
clientsite.wp_users                                OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_api_keys                 OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies     OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta           OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_order_items              OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta        OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens           OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_sessions                 OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations  OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods    OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones           OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations       OK
clientsite.wp_woocommerce_tax_rates                OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_categories                OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_chains                    OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_clients_page              OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_file_categories           OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_files                     OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_files_download_log        OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_group_clients             OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_groups                    OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_login_redirects           OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_messages                  OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_objects_assigns           OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_payments                  OK
clientsite.wp_wpc_client_portal_page_categories    OK
clientsite.wp_wpuf_transaction                     OK
Success: Database checked.
```

WP CLI Tables command gives the following:

```
clientsite % wp db tables
wp_users
wp_usermeta
wp_posts
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_terms
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_term_relationships
wp_termmeta
wp_commentmeta
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
```

wp-config.php contains the below.

```
clientsite % cat wp-config.php
define('DB_NAME', 'clientsite');
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. After some more specific google searching and needing to use quotes (originally just kept returning the wp-cli docs page), I found something on the github issues page. Apparently `wp db tables` only finds the default tables registered to $wpdb, and not all the tables in the database. This is resolved by using `--all-tables` at the end of my commands.

For reference: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2474